# C# - Nunit and sealed class

Tags: c#, nunit

I have these classes.

- class ParentViewModel

  ```
    public ParentViewModel(
                  AViewModel A,
                  BViewModel B)
    { 
        // assigning to variables 
    }

    public bool HasBeenFilled => A.HasBeenFilled || B.HasBeenFilled
    public bool AnotherMethod => A.PropertyA && B.PropertyB
  ```
- class AViewModel (sealed)

  ```
    public bool HasBeenFilled => // some logic here
    public bool PropertyA => // some logic here
  ```
- class BViewModel (sealed)

  ```
    public bool HasBeenFilled => // some logic here
    public bool PropertyB => // some logic here
  ```

Now, if I want to test the ParentViewModel for methods HasBeenFilled and AnotherMethod I would write something like:

```
public void Test_HasBeenFilled()
{
   var mockA = new Mock<AViewModel>(); // here comes the issue
   var mockB = new Mock<BViewModel>();

   mockA.Setup(x => x.HasBeenFilled).Returns(true); // what I want to test
   mockB.Setup(x => x.HasBeenFilled).Returns(true);
   var viewModel = new ParentViewModel(mockA.Object, mockB.Object);  

   Assert.Equals(viewModel.HasBeenFilled == true);
}
```

The issue is that I cannot create mocks over a sealed class.
I could create a base class for AViewModel and BViewModel but then in my parent class (f.e) I have to cast it to the specific object in the 'AnotherMethod' (for accessing PropertyA and Property B) --> what happen when I'll try to test it? My test will be like:

```
public void Test_AnotherMethod()
{
   var mockA = new Mock<AViewModelBase>();
   var mockB = new Mock<BViewModelBase>();

   // cannot setup PropertyA and PropertyB here
   var viewModel = new ParentViewModel(mockA.Object, mockB.Object);

   Assert.Equals(viewModel.AnotherMethod == true); // I would expect an error
}
```

Another solution could be to create specific interface for both AViewModel and BViewModel but, to me, it feels like unnecessary (from development side). It seems like the unit tests are driven heavily my design.

So, my question: How would you address this scenario? Is all about a bad design?

Comment: I’d just use the actual classes in my tests

Comment: Doesn't that make my unit tests dependant on AViewModel and BViewModel? An error in those classes will make the unit tests fail.

Comment: _“An error in those classes will make the unit tests fail”_ - isn’t that the point of having tests?

Comment: IMO, the test should fail if the class I'm testing is not working as expected, not if another dependency has an issue. That's the reason for mocking. Anyway, I moved for creating interfaces for my dependency class.